# Маршруты не работают PHP-MVC

Tags: php, mvc, controller, route

Друзья у меня несколько вопросов по этой теме.
Сайт должен работать на нескольких языков (Английском , Русском и на Польском) .Для этого я создал контроллеры с классами `En , Rus , Pol`.

Кантроллер для Английского `En`

```
class En
{
   public function index()
   {
      include("view/index.php);
      return true;
   }

    public function about()
   {
      include("view/about.php);
      return true;
   }

    public function templates()
   {
      include("view/template.php);
      return true;
   }

    public function contact()
   {
      include("view/contact.php);
      return true;
   }
}
```

Таким образом устроены  классы `Rus` и `Pol`.

Для обработки каждого контроллера я создал класс `Router`

```
class Router
{
    private $routes = array(

       "en" => "en/index",
       "en/home" => "en/index",
       "en/home/subscribe" => "en/subscribe",
       "en/about" => "en/about",
       "en/template" => "en/template",
       "en/contact"  => "en/contact",
       "rus" => "rus/index",
       "rus/home" => "rus/index",
       "rus/home/subscribe" => "rus/subscribe",
       "rus/about" => "rus/about",
       "rus/template" => "rus/template",
       "rus/contact"  => "rus/contact",
       "pol" => "pol/index",
       "pol/home" => "pol/index",
       "pol/home/subscribe" => "pol/subscribe",
       "pol/about" => "pol/about",
       "pol/template" => "pol/template",
       "pol/contact"  => "pol/contact"


    );

    private $url;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->routes;
    }

    public function addRoutes()
    {
        if (!empty($_GET["url"])) 
        {
            $this->url = trim($_GET["url"], "/");

            foreach ($this->routes as $key => $value) 
            {
                if (preg_match("~$key~", $this->url)) 
                {
                    $segment = explode("/", $value);

                    $controllerName = ucfirst(array_shift($segment));
                    $actionName = array_shift($segment);


                    $controllrFile = "controller/" . $controllerName . ".php";

                    if (file_exists($controllrFile)) 
                    {
                        include_once($controllrFile);
                    }

                    $object = new $controllerName;
                    $object->$actionName();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

С помощью массива `$routes` передаются имя контроллера и метод.

Первый вопрос.
Работает только первый маршрут для каждого контроллера.Как можно исправить.

Второй вопрос.
Как можно сдеалть чтоб главной странице первым подключался "англиский конроллер "

Заранее Спасибо

Comment: Контроллер не должен быть языковозависимым

Comment: Можете подробно  обяснить  ??

Comment: Для русского, английского и др. языков должен быть один контроллер, а не по одному для каждого языка. Достаточно подробно объяснил? Для этих целей можно (нужно) использовать http://www.php.su/gettext